# How can I retrieve datetiime from mongodb? By comparing the data with jDateChosser Java

Tags: java, mongodb, datetime, datetime-format, simpledateformat

```
private void showdataTable_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    try {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss'Z'");  //set date format

        String set = df.format(dateChoos1.getDate());           //add value to set

        BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        whereQuery.put("datetimes", set);                       //where date via set(date)

        DBCursor cursor = table.find(whereQuery);
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            DBObject obj = cursor.next();
            String ip_address = (String) obj.get("ip_address");
            String mac_address = (String) obj.get("mac_address");
            Date datetimes = (Date) obj.get("datetimes");
            String url = (String) obj.get("url");
            model.insertRow(model.getRowCount(), new Object[]{datetimes, ip_address, mac_address, url});
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of "Something went wrong." you should print a proper error message (e.g. `e.getMessage()` - it may help you solving the problem.

Comment: it don't have error, But I think datetime format is not match whit datetime format in mongoDB. Becuz it it don't have error and nothing shows.

Comment: Whether anything shows or not, you should follow the advice offered by @WernfriedDomscheit. If you don't follow (good) advice, the chances of getting help are vastly reduced. BTW - This would fail (or work) just as well from a command line app. Debug and test it there. This has nothing to do with Swing. Tag removed.

Comment: We don't know your data but bear in mind, `Date` object has resolution of milliseconds. Is the time in MongoDB **exactly** the time in your query. You may also have a look at time zones.

Comment: What is the datatype of `datetimes` in MongoDB? `date`? `datetime`? `timestamp` with ot without time zone?

Comment: Don’t process your date and time as a string. Keep it in a proper date-time object such as `LocalDate` (for a date) or `Instant` (for a point in time). (Do an effort to find the exactly right type.) Hardcoding `Z` as a literal in your format pattern string is wrong, it’s an offset (of 0) from UTC. I recommend that you use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) for your date and time work (not `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`).

Comment: This should be helpful: [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2). Or [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54907501/5772882).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format, `YYYY-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss'Z'` is not correct. Let's discuss everything which is wrong with this format.

1. **You have used `Y` instead of `y`:** The symbol `Y` is used for `Week year` while `y` is used for `Year`. Check [Difference between year-of-era and week-based-year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431882/difference-between-year-of-era-and-week-based-year) to learn more about it.
2. **You have used `mm` for month:** The correct symbol for the month is `M`.
3. **You have used `MM` for minutes:** The correct symbol for the minute is `m`.
4. **You have enclosed `Z` within single quotes:** The symbol, `Z` is used for `Time zone` whereas `'Z'` is nothing but a character literal. Probably you want to format the timezone offset of `+00:00` as `Z` and for this, you should in fact use `X`.

So, the correct format is as follows:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX
```

**A demo with the suggested format:**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = calendar.getTime();
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-01-14T08:13:01Z
```

Note that the date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Use [`Date#toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--) to convert a `java.util.Date` object (the legacy type) to `java.time.Instant` (the modern type). `Instant` represents an instantaneous point on the time-line and should be just enough for most of your JSON operations. The [`Instant#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString--) returns the date-time string with UTC timezone offset which is compliant with [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = calendar.getTime();
        Instant instant = date.toInstant();
        // Print the value of instant#toString
        System.out.println(instant);

        OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(odt);
        // Custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(dtf.format(odt));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-01-14T08:28:35.659Z
2021-01-14T08:28:35.659Z
2021-01-14T08:28:35Z
```

Comment: Thank sir, I'll try it

Comment: ok, Format is change but I can't query where "datetime" why?

whereQuery.put("datetimes", s);   it not work?

Comment: @SuttipongKamwongsa - I do not have expertise on MongoDB and therefore I can only suggest you some links on SO e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6840540/10819573

Comment: @OleV.V. - Thanks for the feedback and support. Yes, that's what I have mentioned in the answer: `Instant represents an instantaneous point on the time-line and should be just enough for most of your JSON operations. The Instant#toString returns the date-time string with UTC timezone offset which is compliant with ISO-8601 standards.`. The reason why I also added the custom format part is that the OP hasn't mentioned the fraction of second in the requirement. Apart from this, this part also demonstrates the use of DTF in comparison to SDF.